# Can't edit records using best-in-place gem for Rails 3.0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, best-in-place

I'm trying to get the [best-in-place gem](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) to work on a Rails 3.0 app but nothing seems to work. I can't click on any of the objects to edit them.

This is what I've done so far (following the GitHub instructions from the link above as well as the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing):

In my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 0.2.0'
```

I also ran `rails g best_in_place:setup` since I'm on 3.0 and it generated a `best_in_place.js` file into `public/javascripts`.

And finally to display the records to be edited in-place:

```
<div class="profileGains">"<%= best_in_place @project, :my_quote %>"</div>
```

I'm using RESTful routes so I have the `update` action for my project resource.

At this point, the record is displayed but I can't click on it (or any of the other ones).

Any suggestions? I'm new to JS and really stuck.

**EDIT:** I created an `application.js` file in which I added the following code:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place

$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Activating Best In Place */
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

I also tried the suggestion in the comments by Richlewis to add a script tag in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/best_in_place.js"></script>
```

Finally, I tried changing `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` to
`<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>` in my `application.html.erb` layout file.

And again, best-in-place doesn't work.

**UPDATE:** When inspecting the element using Chrome I found this error displayed in the logs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'best_in_place' 
application.js line 7
```

Any idea what this means?

Comment: I assume you are requiring Jquery in application.js and i would put the best_in_place.js in the asset pipeline rather than public

Comment: Well this app doesn't have the asset pipeline since it's running Rails 3.0. Also, there is no application.js file; I thought about adding one but what exactly would I put in there? Also, I do have a jQuery.js file. Since there is no asset pipeline would I need to require jQuery in my application layout file?

Comment: apologies, though 3.0 had asset pipeline, my mistake, well i guess then you will need to call the JS from the app/layout file ie <script type="text/javascript" src="pathtoyourjsfile"></script> within the <head>

Comment: No worries. So I tried a few things, including your suggestion, but nothing seems to work. The project fields are displayed but I can't click to edit. I edited this post to include these extra steps.

Comment: not ideal maybe but can you upgrade to rails 3.2.11? asset pipeline will then be enabled, you can bundle update rails then after you have edited gemfile

Comment: Yeah that just might be the last resort. Thanks for trying!

Comment: well its a good option in my opinion, asset pipeline makes everything much cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question as I figured it out. The `best_in_place.js` file wasn't being rendered in my view because this code `//= require best_in_place` only works for apps with an asset pipeline.

I had to explicitly declare the `best_in_place.js` file in my application layout file. That did the trick.